# How to edit the header banner in the search page in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, header-image

When I enter the search page , the link is

https://www.travelairy.com/?s=test&post_type=product

But at this page the function:

```
$product_taxonomies = get_the_terms($post->ID, $queried_object->taxonomy)
```

return null, and I suspect this is the reason causing the following problem:

The problems are :

1) return "67" for the function that getting logo , `the_field('default_logo', 'option')`, instead of the logo image url

2) the banner is not set, and at the dashboard there seems no related setting

[image]

How to fix that? Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I can't see how that snippet is related to your problem - you'll need to post more relevant code if you expect any help.

Comment: You should ask for support from whoever made the theme for you, otherwise you will need to explain much more on how things are supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is vague but it seems as though you are getting an ID.

You could use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) to get the image source